# com.google.cloud.storage.StorageException: 401 Unauthorized (from local machine)

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage

[GoogleCloudPlatform/storage/cloud-client sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/8a50ab6a8dd220d87b4b259021e53f7f429ca758/storage/cloud-client) could run on GCE VM.
But when running on my local machine(Win7_64x), I got StorageException(401 Unauthorized).
I set up authentication by [this doc](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java).

Could the program access google storage from my local machine?
What else shoud I do to achieve this? or there isn't a way to access google storage outside of GCP?

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.cloud.storage.StorageException: 401 Unauthorized
    at com.google.cloud.storage.spi.v1.HttpStorageRpc.translate(HttpStorageRpc.java:191)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.spi.v1.HttpStorageRpc.create(HttpStorageRpc.java:221)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl$2.call(StorageImpl.java:112)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl$2.call(StorageImpl.java:109)
    at com.google.api.gax.retrying.DirectRetryingExecutor.submit(DirectRetryingExecutor.java:89)
    at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.run(RetryHelper.java:74)
    at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:51)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl.create(StorageImpl.java:108)
    at com.example.storage.QuickstartSample.main(QuickstartSample.java:35)
Caused by: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 401 Unauthorized
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:146)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:321)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1065)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.spi.v1.HttpStorageRpc.create(HttpStorageRpc.java:219)
    ... 7 more
```

**UPDATE(20180309)**:
Running the following code with **[hard-coded Service Account Credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45121635/4983501)**, I could access google storage and download files from it.

```
String SERVICE_ACCOUNT_JSON_PATH = "C:\\gcpconfig\\My First Project-6f9cff47c4f0.json";

Storage storage =
    StorageOptions.newBuilder()
        .setCredentials(
            ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(
                new FileInputStream(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_JSON_PATH)))
        .build()
        .getService();

BlobId blobId = BlobId.of("nmjcloud_jar_test","addons/simple-bean-1.0.jar");
Blob blob = storage.get(blobId);

Path path = Paths.get("D:\\lib\\simple-bean-1.0.jar");
blob.downloadTo(path);

System.out.printf("Download successfully%n");
```

Unfortunately, Setting **GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS** environment variable to the full path of my key json file **still doesn't work** at all. It seems like that the google storage api library doesn't read key json file from `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`.

**[Oh dear. It's My Mistake](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49188658/4983501)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As is mentioned on [java-docs-samples](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/8a50ab6a8dd220d87b4b259021e53f7f429ca758#credentials-example), you need to define some kind of valid credentials for your code to work properly. In your local machine the two valid options are:

1. Set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable pointing to a service account key JSON file path (Make sure to not surround it with double/single quotes)
2. Execute `gcloud auth application-default login`

Given [the doc](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java) you've mentioned has similar instructions, I'd suggest you to try option 2 while at the same time, check for previous mispellings, permissions of the object you are trying to access...

Note: [here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started#creating_a_service_account) you'll find how to create the JSON key file and [here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started#setting_the_environment_variable) how to set the environment variable.

Comment: Running `echo %GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS%` on my local machine returns `"C:\Users\nmj.sys\gcpconfig\My First Project-6f9cff47c4f0.json"`. Does this mean the environment variable is correct?

Comment: On GCE VM, the program worked well after I set this environment variable. Running `echo $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` on GCE VM returns `/home/niaomingjian/gcpconfig/My First Project-6f9cff47c4f0.json`.

Comment: can you try `type %GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS%` and verify that the contents of the json file are shown?

Comment: The OS of my local machine is Win7_64x.

Comment: I found out "C:\Users\nmj.sys\gcpconfig\My First Project-6f9cff47c4f0.json" is fault. Do not need to use **quotation marks** in the value.

Comment: I am very glad to hear that. It was hard to spot and even more given the 'type command' test did not complain about it. I've edited my answer to reflect the 'quoting trap'. Feel free to accept it if you agree with me in that the mistake made does not invalidate my answer.

Comment: In my case `gcloud auth application-default login` did the trick